# ToggleMenu Removing and adding Classes

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, addclass, removeclass

This is the menu I'm using: spoilers.tumblr.com/tvschedule
And below you can see the script. It works fine as far as the click function concerns, but the hovering is a bit tricky. In order for some classes to be shown, I need to hide others first, but I don't want them hidden anymore once the hovering is over. I don't really know how to explain this properly, but if you to my page, you can see it for yourself.

I hope someone is able to help me out here. :)

P.S. I also tried adding the class back after hovering, but that doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I also tried working with z-index in the css, but that doesn't work either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){



 $("#all").hover(function() {
 $('.morenav').removeClass('hoverednow hoveredhiatus hoveredto hoveredfinished clickedfinished clickedto clickedhiatus clickednow');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredhall")}



);

$("#now").hover(function() {
 $('.morenav').removeClass('hoveredall hoveredhiatus hoveredto hoveredfinished clickedfinished clickedto clickedhiatus');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoverednow")
}


); 

$("#hiatus").hover(function() {
$('.morenav').removeClass('hoveredall hoverednow hoveredto hoveredfinished clickedfinished clickedto');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredhiatus")
});

$("#to").hover(function() {
   $('.morenav').removeClass('hoveredall hoveredhiatus hoverednow hoveredfinished clickedfinished');

$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredto")
}); 

$("#finished").hover(function() {
$('.morenav').removeClass('hoveredall hoverednow hoveredto hoveredhiatus');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredfinished")
 });  

$("#all").click(function() {
$('.morenav').removeClass('clickednow clickedhiatus clickedto clickedfinished');

$(this).closest(".morenav").toggledClass("clickedall")
});  

$("#now").click(function() {
 $('.morenav').removeClass('clickedhiatus clickedall  clickedto clickedfinished');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("clickednow")
});

$("#hiatus").click(function() {
     $('.morenav').removeClass('clickednow clickedall clickedto clickedfinished');

$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("clickedhiatus")
}); 

$("#to").click(function() {
 $('.morenav').removeClass('clickednow clickedall clickedhiatus clickedfinished');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("clickedto")
}); 

$("#finished").click(function() {
$('.morenav').removeClass('clickednow clickedall clickedhiatus clickedto');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("clickedfinished")
}); 


});</script>
```

CSS

```
.morenav.hoveredall {background:#f0f0f0; position:fixed; z-index:9999999; -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}

.morenav.clickedall {background:#f0f0f0;  -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}


.morenav.hoverednow {background:#6E0420;  -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}

.morenav.clickednow {background:#6E0420;  -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}
.morenav.hoveredhiatus {background:teal;  -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}
.morenav.clickedhiatus {background:teal;  -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}
.morenav.hoveredto {background:#CFBE27 ; -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}
.morenav.clickedto {background:#CFBE27 ; -moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s;}
.morenav.hoveredfinished {background:#FA6900 ;-moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s; }
.morenav.clickedfinished {background:#FA6900 ;-moz-transition-duration:1s;

-webkit-transition-duration:1s;

-o-transition-duration:1s; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hovering, try defining both the handlerIn and handlerOut functions. Refer here for more: http://api.jquery.com/hover/
The problem with above code is that you are checking only for when mouse hovers over it. You remove the classes, but there is no addition of them back when the mouse moves away.

So the code should start like this:

```
$("#finished").hover(function() {
$('.morenav').removeClass('hoveredall hoverednow hoveredto hoveredhiatus');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredfinished")
}, function() {
$('.morenav').addClass('hoveredall hoverednow hoveredto hoveredhiatus');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hoveredfinished")
});
```

Do like this for everywhere there is a hover.

Comment: That doens't work since that just applies the hoveredfinished class everytime. (You can see it now my page: http://spoiler.tumblr.com/tvschedule )

Comment: toggleClass removes hoverfinished when it is present and adds when it is absent. Also, where is it in your page?

Comment: It's the topmenu with the five different colors.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed I provided you with the wrong link. It's this page: http://spoilers.tumblr.com/tvschedule

Comment: I don't see the problem there. For example, When I hover over now airing, the area around it gets coloured and the text becomes white. When I remove the cursor, it is back to normal. Isn't that what you wanted? Edit: I think you have decided to just go with toggleClass. :D

Comment: Hi Thansk for the help, but yeah, my initial plan was for the area above the links to change color on hover as well, but I settled for this! ;)